# Is websocket Send/Receive thread-safe (go routine-safe)?

Tags: concurrency, websocket, go

When writing a websocket server in GO (in my case using the JSON codec), is it safe to have two different Go routines for handling sending and receiving of data on the same connection?

Since `websocket.JSON.Receive` pauses and waits to receive data, I thought a separate Go routine for handling sending of data would be a working solution unless concurrent sending/receiving is not possible on the same connection.

So, is the working example below bad practice?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "code.google.com/p/go.net/websocket"
)

const queueSize = 20

type Input struct {
    Cmd    string
}

type Output struct {
    Cmd    string
}

func Handler(ws *websocket.Conn) {

    msgWrite := make(chan *Output, queueSize)
    var in Input

    go writeHandler(ws, msgWrite)

    for {

        err := websocket.JSON.Receive(ws, &in)

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            break
        } else {
            msgWrite <- &Output{Cmd: "Thanks for your message: " + in.Cmd}
        }
    }
}

func writeHandler(ws *websocket.Conn, out chan *Output) {
    var d *Output
    for {
        select {
        case d = <-out:
            if err := websocket.JSON.Send(ws, &d); err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err.Error())
            } else {
                fmt.Println("> ", d.Cmd)
            }
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    http.Handle("/echo", websocket.Handler(Handler));
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":1235", nil);
    if err != nil {
        panic("ListenAndServe: " + err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Println("Server running")
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can call Send, Receive and Close on a websocket connection concurrently, like you can with all [net.Conn](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#Conn)'s in Go. A short excerpt from the official docs:

> Multiple goroutines may invoke methods on a Conn simultaneously.

Additionally, the websocket package also introduces some Codecs for sending / writing Messages  or JSON data that might occupy multiple frames atomically. If you look at the source, you can see that the Send and Receive method of the Codec type will hold either the read or the write lock.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I missed to look in the net-package for the answer, so I am glad you pointed it out.

Comment: @tux21b where do you see that it will try to combine multiple frames to form a single json message? I don't see it in the source and the comment before the method doesn't indicate it either: "// Receive receives __single frame from ws__, unmarshaled by cd.Unmarshal and stores in v." Emphasis mine.

Answer (score 1):

Quoted from http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/websocket

Concurrency

Connections support one concurrent reader and one concurrent writer.

Applications are responsible for ensuring that no more than one goroutine calls the write methods (NextWriter, SetWriteDeadline, WriteMessage, WriteJSON, EnableWriteCompression, SetCompressionLevel) concurrently and that no more than one goroutine calls the read methods (NextReader, SetReadDeadline, ReadMessage, ReadJSON, SetPongHandler, SetPingHandler) concurrently.

The Close and WriteControl methods can be called concurrently with all other methods.